# Import raster tiles in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, tiles, shaded-relief

I have much amount of raster tiles with hillshaded relief, that I've tiled using QGIS (Qtiles). And I'm trying to import these raster tiles into PostGIS. I have searched about my question but found only cases connected with importing rasters into Postgis (raster2pgsql) or tiling rasters in Postgis.
I've tried to use Geoserver (Build an image pyramid and load them to Geoserver), but it's necessary to retile (gdal_retile) initial raster and the result differs from Qtiles (gdal_retile split image by other parameters and assigns other names to tiles, not as slippy map tilenames format).
Further I would like to add tiled rasters on my map canvas in QGIS using TileLayer Plugin (This plugin can render only tile maps in the tile format of Slippy Map).
Has anybody an idea, how to import tiled raster?
Sooner or later I wonder it would be possible to add my tiles from PostGIS in QGIS and create beautiful maps:)

Comment: Why not using raster2pgsql?

Comment: Because my enormous data (DEM) are approximately > 50GB and data access will be very slow. And it's not necessary to make some analysis with it, I need nice picture only with hillshaded and colored relief

Comment: Your goal is not clear. You want to import your tiles into PostGIS or you want to display (import?) them in QGIS? Please rephrase your question more clearly.

Comment: I want to display them in QGIS. DEM are very large and export of maps takes too much time. And not less important to have access data for many users

Comment: Did you build overviews on your rasters?

Comment: You mean pyramids? No, how does it help me? I'm pretty sure building the pyramids takes much more space than tiles

Comment: But they would display and print much faster.